# BigQuery Collation

Tags: google-bigquery

How can I set a collation order in BigQuery?

I want something like this

```
SELECT Place
FROM Locations
ORDER BY Place COLLATE "en_CA"
```

I can't find any documentation other than COLLATE is a reserved word in BigQuery.

BigQuery is sorting the following Strings in [a..zA..Z] order:

E.g.

- ant
- bee
- cat
- Apple
- Banana
- Cantaloupe

Is there a way to ask BigQuery to sort in [aA..zZ] order?

- ant
- Apple
- bee
- Banana
- cat
- Cantaloupe

Answer (score 1):

Below example is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
create temp function collate_order(text string) as ((
  select string_agg(chr(1000 * ascii(lower(c)) - ascii(c)), '' order by offset)
  from unnest(split(text)) c with offset
));
with `project.dataset.Locations` as (
  select 'ant' as Place union all
  select 'Apple' union all
  select 'bee' union all
  select 'apple' union all
  select 'cat' union all
  select 'Banana' union all
  select 'Cantaloupe' 
)
select Place
from `project.dataset.Locations`
order by collate_order(Place)
```

with output

[image]

Forgot to mention - obviously you can extend this approach to handle unicode text by replacing `ascii` to `unicode` function

Answer (score 0):

You can try following query it will work for your requirement, it will sort data in [aA..zZ] order :-

```
SELECT Place
FROM Locations
ORDER BY upper(Place)
```